# How to fix fatal error LNK1120 in a C++ game using SFML?

Tags: c++, oop, sfml

I have recently been writing a game in C++ using SFML, but recently tried to make it more object-oriented. However, I got this error: 1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl gameMain(void)" (?gameMain@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main

Program Code: http://pastie.org/private/qsxw1qefsrhv3rddoqcga

I am newer to object-oriented programming, and would appreciate it if I could have help fixing  a possible egregious mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a `gameMain()` global function, but you implemented it in `QuadraPong`.

If you want to use the one in `QuadraPong,` you have to create an object of that class.

Example:

```
int main()
{
      QuadraPong game;
      game.gameMain();
}
```